# Binding touch events to just those elements with a class & not its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, bind

I'm trying to convert hovers to touches for all menu list items that have a class of `.menu-item-has-children` ONLY not its children (unless they too have the class .menu-item-has-children). There are other menu items that do not have this class assigned to it and I'd like to leave those alone. Currently my code below stops the links being touched/clicked but I need to re-enable clicks/touches for children links of `.menu li.menu-item-has-children` except for any children that have the class `.menu-item-has-children` How do I fix this so that only `.menu-item-has-children` links are targeted?

So I have this HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <div class="drop">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="#">Link text</a>
            <div class="drop">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Link text</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
                        <a href="#">Link text</a>
                        <div class="drop">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Link text</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Link text</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link text</a>
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

**My jQuery**

```
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
      return false;
      $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
});
// Trying to re-bind the click for child links that do not have the .menu-item-has-children class?
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .drop li').bind('touchstart touchend', function() {
      return true;
});
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and lacks MCVE. Please explain yourself and show with working code (even if it shows something that doesn't behave like you want it to, and explain what is missing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently my code below stops the links being touched/clicked but I need to re-enable clicks/touches for children links of .menu li.menu-item-has-children

Returning `false` means the execution of the script will terminate on the line where you are returning it. You are returning `false` before the `$(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');` line of code is *ever* executed. Try swapping the two lines as such:

```
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');         
    return false;
});
```

***NOTE:*** If I've understood your problem correctly, then you don't want a child li to generate the same touch event which doesn't have the class `.menu-item-has-children`.

Now suppose you want to do some other stuff by touching one of the children associated with `li.menu-item-has-children` (not having the same class). First provide the code in the handler to whatever you want, then return `false` soon after to prevent the `touch` event on the *current* element from bubbling to `li.menu-item-has-children`:

```
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .drop li:not(.menu-item-has-children)').bind('touchstart touchend', function() {
      // do some stuff here 
      return false;
});
```

**Notice the use of `:not()` filter which excludes any child li element with the class `.menu-item-has-children`.**

*I've tried to reproduce your problem (with the only difference that I have bound the elements to the `click` event)* [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/0uy28dc0/2/). *Try removing the `return false` set on the `.child` handler to see the change in behavior.*

Comment: The problem is that the first block of code works, in that the hovers work when touched BUT it also means I cannot click a child link to go to another page. This is what needs fixing, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes I have implemented it and understand the concept jsFiddle but child links do not work. Its like return false is being applied to all of its children and stopping me from using their default behaviour

Comment: Child links are not working since they have no `href` set, and currently are having just a `#`. Am I right?

Comment: Meanwhile, `return false` stops event bubbling or better known as event propagation - which acts as an inner element raises an event, and that event _bubbles_ up until it reaches the particular parent. This is the exact opposite of event capturing, which jQuery doesn't implement by default.

Comment: No I've put your code into the real life situation where links really are links  and they do nothing when touched, other than play the hover. I need them to link to the page their supposed to link to.

Comment: @egr103, I think I found the problem with the links, check the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/0uy28dc0/3/). The links weren't working since the click on the `a` tag has to bubble up to the `window` object so that the `window` changes the location. By tweaking the second block of code with `window.location = $(this).attr('href');` you can get round this problem. Note that DO NOT remove the `return false` which comes right after it.

Comment: Brilliant, OK now we're getting somewhere, in terms of getting hovers and links working, this is done, however in the real site with real links, its adding the word undefined on the end of the current page URL and returning a 404. Its not getting the href from the clicked/touched link. Any ideas? This is also the case for your updated jsFiddle

Comment: Yep, my bad. You should change the selector `'.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .drop li:not(.menu-item-has-children)'` to `'.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .drop li:not(.menu-item-has-children) a'` (added the `a` in the end.) [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/0uy28dc0/4/)

Comment: Brilliant that did the trick! Thanks for your help! So happy this is fixed! I will award you the bounty but I can't do so for 16hours

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `e.stopPropagation()` instead of `return false`

```
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
  return false;
  $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
});
// Trying to re-bind the click for child links that do not have the .menu-item-has-children class?

$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .drop li').bind('touchstart touchend', function() {
  return true;
});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where I need to use this but I'm afraid that doesn't work when I replace the return true; statement in the second bind event

Comment: sorry it was a typo i edited : i was talking about your return false

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite. I have stopped the links being touched/clicked but I need to re-enable clicks/touches for children links of .menu li.menu-item-has-children except for any children that have the class .menu-item-has-children. See updated question

Comment: after your return nothing is executed because it is never reached !

Comment: I thought return:true would re-instate clicks to default? If this doesn't work how would I re-enable links?

Comment: Yes you're right ! i was talking about your `return false;` followed by code in the function. This part will never be reached

Comment: I see your point but after switching the two lines of code around and using your stop propogation, Hovers no longer work but clicks do work. This isn't what I wanted. I think I'm really misunderstanding you here. Here's my new code using your solution: http://pastebin.com/CiZPukUv

Comment: in your second part you just return true, instead you have to precise what you want to occur !

Comment: instead of `return true;` try `console.log('true');` and see in your console if it works

Comment: Forgive the silly question but I'm testing on iPad's. Do they have console?

Comment: try with alert but if you have many thing you will have to click ok many times

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu li.menu-item-has-children').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
   $('.menu li.menu-item-has-children > .drop li').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Events in html bubble up through each of their parents, activating any bound functions.  This is called event propagation.

As other answers have mentioned, `return false;` prevents the event from propagating up.  Changing a child element to have `return true` will have no effect as the event will still stop at the parent element.  You cannot make it propagate further by altering the child event.

What you can do is modify the parent event to only return false if the event was triggered on it.  You can get the element that the event was triggered on by using `event.target`.  The following code will only return false when the event was directly triggered on the element that the method is bound too.

```
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children > a').bind('touchstart touchend', function(e) {
      return event.target !== this;
      // I've left this line in because it's in your example,
      // but it will never do anything if it is after the return statement
      $(this).toggleClass('hover_effect');
});
```